# help identify potted plant with long leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

can anyone help identify this plant we have? When the flower blooms, it comes up as this long stalk with white flowers at the top of the stalk. [image: long leaves plant without trunk, above view]

[image: the same plant from front view]

Comment: Pictures of the flowers would be helpful in ID.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your description of the flowers and the shape of the leaves, it might be an Agapanthus:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a Haemanthus albiflos,also called paintbrush.

Comment: Are you sure ?  When I google **Haemanthus albiflos** the pictures show plants with rounder leaves.

Comment: Agreed that it's likely a bulb in the Amaryllis family.